# Can I create a custom text field and keyboard for iOS w/o subclassing UIControl?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, custom-controls, uitextfield, subclass

My app will require the user to input chemistry formulas (H2O, Na^2+), and since subscripts and superscripts may make the typing process confusing for the user, I have decided to make a custom keyboard.

When the user types in a number as a subscript, it should be displayed as a subscript on the screen. The only way I've found to do this is using NSAttributedString, which apparently only works with CoreText. Since I can't have CoreText in a UITextField, I need to create a custom text field as well. I was looking into UITextView, but the documentation reads that the font styles must be consistent throughout the text, meaning I can't have subscripts.

Do I need to subclass UIControl for both cases and start from scratch? Or is there an alternative class I can start with that already has some of the properties of keyboard/textfield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to create your own subclass of `UIView`.

But you can easily support keyboard input by adopting the `UIKeyInput` protocol, overriding `canBecomeFirstResponder` so it returns `YES` and adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
    [self addGestureRecognizer:
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)]];
```

I you want to allow the user to select ranges of text and use autocorrection, that's harder: you need to adopt the protocol `UITextInput`.

Customizing the keyboard is really simple:

- either, you override `inputAccessoryView` which allow you to display a custom view attached to the keyboard,
- either, you override `inputView` so it returns a custom view that will be displayed in place of the keyboard.